# How to keep order in Java 9 Set.of

Tags: java, set

I've noted while testing that the new `Set.of` method of Java 9 doesn't return an ordered implementation of a Set.

How can I use such utilities and still get an ordered collection? Or there is no way, only the traditional ones?

Ex.:

```
Set mySet = Set.of(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3, 4});
//mySet can come in any order when I iterate over it
```

**EDIT**
Forgot to mention, I need to keep the order that comes in the array.

From the answers it seems like using the good and old `new LinkedHashSet(Arrays.asList(myArr))` is still the way.

Comment: Well, the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#immutable) states: "The iteration order of set elements is unspecified and is subject to change."

Comment: Use `SortedSet.of`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe there is no such method, just looked at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html)

Comment: Actually there is a method `SortedSet.of` - which is just the overloaded version of `Set.of`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The immutable `Set`s created by `Set.of` make no guarantee about the iteration order of their elements. You could use a specific implementation that does, such as a [`LinkedHashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html):

```
Set<Integer> mySet = new LinkedHashSet<>(List.of(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3, 4}));
```

Answer (score 2):

The Javadoc explicitely states:  "The iteration order of set elements is unspecified and is subject to change."

You could wrap your set in a sorted set like `TreeSet` (I also added some generics)

```
 SortedSet<Integer> mySet = new TreeSet<>(Set.of(1, 2, 3, 4));
```

If you need a set that maintains insertion order, you will have to use a `LinkedHashSet` instead (note that this is not a sorted set).

```
  Set<Integer> mySet = new LinkedHashSet<>(List.of(1, 2, 3, 4));
```

Comment: This approach still gets them out of order, because you use Set.of result (which is unordered).

Comment: No. Set.of is unordered, but a TreeSet is always sorted.

Comment: Yep, but it doesn't maintain the order of the elements you have inserted, just the order of what it received from the underlying set.

Comment: No, thats wrong. It orderes them in their natural order, as defined by the `Comparable` interface, which is implemented by `Integer`. That's a sorted set, no one asked for a set which maintains the insertion order.

Comment: true, forgot to mention, sorry

Comment: Using a `LinkedHashSet` is the right idea, but the implementation here is wrong - by using `Set.of` you already lost the original order, and wrapping it with a `LinkedHashSet` is too late. See my answer for an example that would work.

Comment: Right, I fixed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't using `Set.of`.  That gives you an [immutable `Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#immutable) instead of one which can be ordered.

The only way you could do this is if you build a `TreeSet` instead (which *is* ordered if the object if `Comparable`, or you can specify your own `Comparator`).

```
Set<Integer> mySet = new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4));
```

Comment: Isn't the "inherited" `of(...)` method the same for `Set` and `SortedSet`? In that case the resulting set would still not be ordered.

Comment: Good point @Thomas; I didn't anticipate that.  I'll remove that hint.

Comment: Note that being immutable has nothing to do with being ordered.